# Check keypress types inside a polymer element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The following polymer element has an on-keypress event listener:

```dart
<polymer-element name="custom-element">
  <template>
    <input type="text" on-keypress="{{print}}" value="{{text}}">
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="custom.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I want the element to listen for specific keypress types (e.g., enter, backspace, etc.). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly listen to specific key codes only, but of course you can check the keycode and act accordingly in your listener:

```dart
// method name based on the template in the question
void print(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    int code = (e as KeyboardEvent).keyCode;
    switch(code) {
    case 13:
        // this is enter
    case 8:
        // this is backspace, but not in keypress event
    }
}
```

As the comment said, you can't check for more "advanced" keys in `on-keypress`, you would have to use `on-keydown` or `on-keyup` for that.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about those three parameters before.